# Mongoose find-query: Sort JSON-Array by Date

Tags: json, sorting, mongoose

I tried this mongoose-query and have no idea why this sort doesn't work (found syntax on stackoverflow so no Idea what I did wrong again).
Tried to replace exec with find, doesnt work either.

```
model.find({'id':req.params.id}).sort({date:-1}).limit(10).exec(function(err, jsonarray){...};
```

My schema and jsondata is like that:

```
var messageSchema  = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  name: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  message:
        {
            messagetype: String,
            timestamp: Number,
            messagestatus: String
        }
}, {collection: 'test'});
```

Otherwise could sort it by message.timestamp but I have no idea how..
Thanks in advance.

Even tried it like that.. I'm stuck.

```
json.sort(function(a, b) {
return parseFloat(a.message.timestamp) - parseFloat(b.message.timestamp);
});
```

Update: Data looks like that:

```
[ { id: 215456740,
  name: 'Max',
  type: 'freezer',
  _id: 57513933c25d06630a3ef887,
  __v: 0,
  message: 
   { messagetype: 'Standard message',
     timestamp: 1464940851375,
     messagestatus: 'red'
    } 
},
 { id: 215456740,
name: 'Tobi',
type: 'center',
_id: 5751393bc25d06630a3ef888,
__v: 0,
   message: 
 { messagetype: 'Standard message',
   timestamp: 1464940859265,
   messagestatus: 'white'
  } 
}]
```

Yes, it's intentional, multiple messages for one Id.
This is the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.sort({_id: -1})

Used autocreated _id as it has an embedded Date. Worked afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The query is sorting on a non-existent property `date`:

```
.sort({ date : -1 })
```

Instead, try this:

```
.sort({ 'message.timestamp' : -1 })
```

Comment: Tried, doesn't work either sadly.
Feels like it gets the parameter but doesn't sort it there or doesn't reload the new array.

Comment: Just to be sure: it's _intentional_ that you have multiple documents with the same `id` property, right? Can you add a list of results (redacted or compacted, just showing the `message` property would be enough) from the query to your question?

Comment: Updated it for a better view, appreciating your help.

Comment: @LinkM that data looks sorted on timestamp, though?

Comment: Yes but wrong messages on top, the newest stored message should appear on top, right now and by default (cause of store order) the newest is on bottom.. Tried with .sort({ 'message.timestamp' : 1 }) as well, that should reverse it but nothing happens.

Comment: Nice, found a solution, not for sorting it like it's pretended to be but json.reverse(); did it for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nevermind,as I just limit(10) for my query, seems like i get the right order now but always the 10 oldest JSON-array entries instead of the 10 newest.. Therefore this question is still open.